# Need something like %EVAL for date functions

Tags: sas

I'm trying to have a SAS data set automatically limit the results based on date but don't want to manually have to manually change the date through a %Let statement.

If I try

```
%let BeginDate = %EVAL(MDY(MONTH(TODAY()), 1, YEAR(TODAY()));
```

I get a "Open code statement recursion detected"... I've tried &SYSFUNC and &SYSEVALF but no luck either.  It seems like this should be much simpler... any suggestions would surely be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Change `%eval` to `%sysfunc` and you'll need a `%sysfunc` in front of the each function. `mdy`, `month`, `today`, `year`.

Answer (score 3):

@Joe's method is the most straightforward. Additionally, if you wanted to do this in a datastep with similar syntax you could do:

```
data _null_;
    call symputx('BeginDate_ds',mdy(month(today()),1,year(today())));
run;

%put &BeginDate_ds.;
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're doing, you either don't need anything, or you need `%SYSFUNC`.

If you want to have `&begindate` evaluate to an actual date value, you would use `%SYSFUNC`.

However, you have *five* functions there - that's going to require a bunch of sysfuncs, though I think we can do two not five.

```
%let begindate = %sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,%sysfunc(today()),0,b));
%put &begindate;
```

We use `INTNX` with the MONTH and B(eginning) options to tell SAS to go ahead 0 months (so current month) and to go to the Beginning of that month.  A second SYSFUNC grabs TODAY().  You could simplify this more:

```
%let begindate = %sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,"&sysdate."d,0,b));
%put &begindate;
```

`&SYSDATE` is a macro variable that stores the system date when SAS was started up; so only use that if you're okay with that (i.e., if SAS likely/definitely started up today).

With SYSFUNC don't forget that you need to drop quotation marks, with the one big exception of the date constant above - that is okay to use them - but note "MONTH" and "b" are not quoted.